# How to execute *.sql file using psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have created an `index.sql` file which contains  index creating script for `95 table`

for example

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS gtab03_vrctrlid_idx cascade;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX gtab03_vrctrlid_idx ON gtab03 USING btree (vrctrlid);
```

I have consolidated all table's `index creating script` to a file called `index.sql`
I need to run the entire script at a time, is it possible to execute the `index.sql` file using `psql`

Comment: Please use the manual when you need it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: You might want to consider using a PL/PgSQL function to do this dynamically based on a query against `information_schema` and a loop over `EXECUTE format(...)`, rather than writing out all the statements manually. Search dba.se for examples.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Following script worked for me,

```
psql -U postgres -d mydb -a -f "D:\index.sql" -- Absolute path to .sql file
```

---

[-U, -a, -f](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html)

Comment: Obviously...but for the good of the community it is easier if they can run the command as it is provided, without having to go digging into the reference to check what this non-obvious flag does. I see you added it, good on you.

Comment: You can also "pipe" it, e.g. `psql -U postgres -d mydb < D:\index.sql`

Answer (score 54):

Is this what you mean?

```
\i e:/myFolder/index.sql;
```

Comment: ; should not be included because this is a psql command and not SQL.

Comment: That doesn't work for me - parameter `\i` is not known in psql.